# C++ execute function with class from array

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointer-to-member, typed-arrays

I need to be able to call a function that is a member of a class by looking up the function pointer in an array. This class will have sub classes that do the same thing but call the parent class if they cannot fund the function. To make matters simple, I have cut out most of the code. What remains is shown below.

The ultimate test is to create:

```
1) Mammal : public Animal
1.1) Cat : public Mammal
1.2) Dog : public Mammal
2) Reptile : public Animal
2.1) Bird : public Reptile
```

I want to build this as cleanly as possible so Uncle Bob Martin would smile down on me. Right now, I think he would just give me a kick in the pants, so any help refactoring this to make it better would be deeply appreciated.

```
class Animal {
public:
#define CMD_EAT             1
#define CMD_SLEEP           2
#define CMD_MAKENOISE       3

private:
    const int _actions;
    const char* _name;

public:
    //  Define a pointer to a function within this class that takes
    //  an INT as its argument
    typedef void(Animal::*animalFunc)(int);

private:
    //  Define an array of pointers to action functions
    animalFunc _actionPointers[];  //<<< COMPILE ERROR: "incomplete type is not allowed"

    //  Define an array of action names
    char* _animalActions[];

public:
    Animal(int actions, char* name) : _actions(actions), _name(name) {
        _actionPointers[_actions] = NULL;
        _animalActions[_actions] = NULL;
        registerCommands();
    }

    //  Define an array of pointers to action functions
    //animalFunc animalCommands[MAX_ANIMAL_CMD];

    //  Register all commands supported by this class
    virtual void registerCommands() {
        registerCommand(CMD_EAT, "EAT", &Animal::eat);
        registerCommand(CMD_SLEEP, "SLEEP", &Animal::sleep);
        registerCommand(CMD_MAKENOISE, "MAKE NOISE", &Animal::makeNoise);
    }

    void registerCommand(int code, char* action, void (Animal::*animalFunc)(int)) {
        _animalActions[code - 1] = action;
        _actionPointers[code - 1] = animalFunc;
    }

    void exec(int code, int value) {
        Serial.print("Executing  ");
        Serial.print(code);
        *(this->_actionPointers[code])(value);  //<<< THIS DOESN'T COMPILE
    }

    const char* getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    //  base class methods
    virtual void eat(int times) {}

    virtual void sleep(int times) {}

    void makeNoise(int times) {}
};

void main() {
    //  Step 1: Create pointer to an instance of an animal object
    Animal *pAnimal = new Animal(3, "ANIMAL");
    pAnimal->exec(CMD_EAT, 1);
    pAnimal->exec(CMD_SLEEP, 1);
}
```

I am getting two compile errors that I haven't been able to get around. They are highlighted in the code.

Comment: I'd 1) drop the `#define`s and use unnamed enum for those constants. 2) Use `std::string` instead of C strings. 3) Use either a `std::vector` or perhaps `std::map` instead of the plain C array. 4) Either use `std::function` and `std::bind` instead of the member function pointers, or just wrap command in a class hierarchy (as in [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)). 5) Use smart pointers instead of plain pointers (in your `main()`). There's really no need to see `new` here, and you avoid memory leaks (such as the one at the of your main, which is luckily harmless).

Comment: Ok, since this is apparently on an AVR without standard c++ library implementation the above is mostly irrelevant (other than #1). The problem with `animalFunc _actionPointers[];` is due to the fact that you can't have arrays with variable size. Since you know the number of commands, just have a fixed size array.

Comment: `*(this->_actionPointers[code])(value);` -- [should be](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#dotstar-vs-arrowstar) `(this->*_actionPointers[code])(value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that can be done is to replace `#define`s with an enum, and add a total command count.

```
#define CMD_EAT             1
#define CMD_SLEEP           2
#define CMD_MAKENOISE       3
```

becomes

```
enum {
     CMD_EAT
     , CMD_SLEEP
     , CMD_MAKENOISE
     , COMMAND_COUNT
};
```

Next, we should make sure the code is const-correct. Since we're using string constants, all the string variables and function arguments should be `char const*` rather than `char*`.

After this, we could combine the function pointer and the name in one structure, since they belong together. Notice that since we have a typedef for the member function pointer, we can use that.

```
struct command_info
{
    animalFunc handler;
    char const* name;
};
```

Since we now know the number of commands at compile time, and we have the above structure, we can have a single fixed-size array:

```
command_info _commands[COMMAND_COUNT];
```

We can also drop the `actions` parameter from the constructor.

Since we have a fixed size array, it's important to validate the index before accessing the array:

```
if (code < COMMAND_COUNT) { //...
```

Next, you have virtual methods, so your class should also have a virtual destructor:

```
virtual ~Animal() {}
```

We're getting close to the end -- next there's a problem with how you [invoke the member function pointer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#dotstar-vs-arrowstar). The correct way (with the above mentioned modifications in mind) is:

```
(this->*_commands[code].handler)(value);
```

Finally, you leak memory at the end of your program.

```
delete pAnimal;
```

However, it would be better to use RAII for resource management. Since you're on AVR and don't have the Standard C++ Library available, you could just define a simple handle class, something along the lines of

```
struct animal_ptr {
    animal_ptr(Animal* a) : ptr(a) {}
    ~animal_ptr() { delete a; }
    Animal* ptr;
}
```

---

### Complete revised code

NB: I commented out the lines involving `Serial`, so that I can compile without it.

```
class Animal 
{
public:
    enum {
        CMD_EAT
        , CMD_SLEEP
        , CMD_MAKENOISE
        , COMMAND_COUNT
    };

    //  Define a pointer to a function within this class that takes
    //  an INT as its argument
    typedef void(Animal::*animalFunc)(int);
    struct command_info
    {
        animalFunc handler;
        char const* name;
    };

public:
    Animal(char const* name)
        : _name(name)
    {
        registerCommands();
    }

    //  Register all commands supported by this class
    virtual void registerCommands() {
        registerCommand(CMD_EAT, "EAT", &Animal::eat);
        registerCommand(CMD_SLEEP, "SLEEP", &Animal::sleep);
        registerCommand(CMD_MAKENOISE, "MAKE NOISE", &Animal::makeNoise);
    }

    void registerCommand(int code, char const* action, animalFunc fn) {
        if (code < COMMAND_COUNT) {
            _commands[code].name = action;
            _commands[code].handler = fn;
        }
    }

    void exec(int code, int value) {
        if (code < COMMAND_COUNT) {
            //Serial.print("Executing  ");
            //Serial.print(code);
            (this->*_commands[code].handler)(value);
        }
    }

    char const* getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    //  base class methods
    virtual void eat(int times) {}

    virtual void sleep(int times) {}

    void makeNoise(int times) {}
    
    
private:
    char const* _name;
    
    //  Define an array of pointers to action functions
    command_info _commands[COMMAND_COUNT];
};

int main() {
    //  Step 1: Create pointer to an instance of an animal object
    Animal *pAnimal = new Animal("ANIMAL");
    pAnimal->exec(Animal::CMD_EAT, 1);
    pAnimal->exec(Animal::CMD_SLEEP, 1);
    delete pAnimal;
}
```

[<kbd>Sample on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8111f32bbcd5d891)

Comment: Clear, simple, concise. Uncle Bob would be proud!

Comment: Thanks. Keep in mind that there are still some things that could probably be done with this -- I'll add some notes tomorrow, need some sleep now :)

Comment: I posted an extension to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500149/refactor-code-that-violates-needless-repition-principle that adds the Mammal class and points out the real problem I am trying to solve: needless repetition. How Can Animal and Mammal (and eventually, Cat & Dog, Reptile and Bird) be tightened up to use the minimum amount of code with virtually no repetition? Let's make Uncle Bob Martin smile!

Answer (score 1):

I have refactored the Animal class to remove lots of noise. Also have used C++11 features. If you dont have c++11, then it can be easily replaced by boost. I have basically changed the way you are doing the registrations. Also I have removed quite a few stuff which did not make sense to me in the current context, but may be important for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class Animal {
public:
  enum Action {
    CMD_EAT = 1,
    CMD_SLEEP,
    CMD_MAKENOISE
  };

private:
    const std::string _name;
    std::map<Action, std::function<void(int)>> _actionsMap;

public:
    Animal(const std::string& name) : _name(name) {
        registerCommands();
    }

    //  Register all commands supported by this class
    virtual void registerCommands() {
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        registerCommand(CMD_EAT,       std::bind(&Animal::eat, this, _1));
        registerCommand(CMD_SLEEP,     std::bind(&Animal::sleep, this, _1));
        registerCommand(CMD_MAKENOISE, std::bind(&Animal::makeNoise, this, _1));
    }

    void registerCommand(Action code, std::function<void(int)> cb) {
      _actionsMap.emplace(code, cb);
    }

    void exec(Action action, int value) {
        //Serial.print("Executing  ");
        //Serial.print(code);
        //TODO: Check if present in map
        _actionsMap[action](value);
    }

    //  base class methods
    virtual void eat(int times) { std::cout << "Eat\n"; }

    virtual void sleep(int times) { std::cout << "Sleep\n"; }

    void makeNoise(int times) {}
};

int main() {
    //  Step 1: Create pointer to an instance of an animal object
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> pAnimal(new Animal("Animal"));
    pAnimal->exec(Animal::CMD_EAT, 1);
    pAnimal->exec(Animal::CMD_SLEEP, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking. I'd probably replace the C string with a `std::string` as well.  Also move the `using namespace std::placeholders;` into `registerCommands()` since it's only needed there. Finally, if c++14 is available, use `make_unique` instead of the `new`.

Comment: Thanks, have made the changes you suggested. I am currently not having c++14 supporting compiler  for make_unique :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I am doing all this on an Arduino platform which doesn't seem to support the std library. I deeply appreciate the quick and detailed response, but I will have to translate it into a form that doesn't use std.

Comment: There is an implementation of the STL for the Arduino, but it takes up a lot of memory and the Arduino only has 32K for programs and 2K for heap and stack, so I need to do this without STD.

Comment: @BobJones The crucial fact that this is for AVR would have been useful to know from the start. That changes the game significantly, you're lacking significant part of the standard by not having the standard library available. Please, update your question appropriately.